# MacOS lock screen password entry loses keystrokes

Tags: macos, password

I have a consistent issue where the MacOS lock screen (latest MacBook Pro) loses keystrokes.  It freezes for 1-2 full seconds and whatever I typed does not appear.

This is very annoying since I have to type my password 2-3 times.  It happens every day.

Any ideas what I might do to speed it up or at least just make sure the characters are queued instead of lost?  I don't have this issue with any other software I use or other parts of MacOS.  (I'm on Monterrey 12.6.)

Comment: I'm on Ventura 13.4.1 and can confirm this behavior.  EVERY DAY.  I have learned to pause when I type my password at the login prompt to give the F***ING OS time to catch up.  And still I have to retype my login password multiple times to get it input correctly.  Since you haven't gotten other replies to this question, I'm guessing it has to do with the company-installed security profiles and other such crapware like Intune.  In which case, nothing to do about it, I guess.

Comment: @jrw32982 still getting something similar on Sonora beta.  Generally typing the pwd is super delayed even on the latest MB Pro.  It seems better at not flat-out losing characters though, maybe - still experimenting.  Would love some direction here but haven't found anything 

Comment: Nope, still losing keystrokes like crazy in Sonora beta.

Comment: Yep, I still lose keystrokes like crazy during that login prompt.  I have to type/pause/type/pause to get them all captured.